# Noob Question Repost: How to Turn this into a working link that still uses the data that is recieved from the Id Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I do not have any former training ect. So if you arent going to be helpful please don't respond, I'm just trying to learn here.

```html
<a id="player-web-Link">View in Depth Stats</a>
```

Which loads this: [image]
Basically I'm using the "Id"= to fill the link that it gets from java script, the info for the link is parsed from a JSON file, it is formatted correctly. if you visit beatsbycayde.com/test/ you can see that the info is getting loaded. But for some reason i can not turn it into a clickable link and pull the info from the id tag into a clickable link, please help.

I've also tried this.

```html
<a href="player-web-Link">View in Depth Stats</a>
```

```html
<a href="<a id="player-web-link" >View in Depth Stats</a>
```

I want to be able to Click a link that is loaded from an id tag
So the id references a .js file that is has parsed a json response ,
what i dont know is how to access an ID inside of an Href element.

I do not know all the proper lingo, I am just ask a question essentially is there a way to turn Load an Id inside of an href element, or is there a way to turn the data received from an Id , into a clickable link. –
this is a repost of an issue as the member recommended i do

this is where the value of player weblink is obtained

```js
fstats = data.Response.data.characters[0].characterBase.characterId, webLink = "braytech.org/2/4611686018429000034/" + fstats + "/legend";
$('#player-f-stats').text(fstats), $('#player-web-Link').text(webLink);
```

this is the ajax request sent to recieve the data

```js
  $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny/2/Account/4611686018429000034/",
        headers: {
          "X-API-Key": apiKey
        },
        success: function(data) {
```

this is what im trying to accomplish

```html
<a id="player-web-Link">View in Depth Stats</a>
```

is converted into a URL that has been defined by the java script, but when i try to access the "player-web-Link" inside of an Href it doesnt work I.E

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to turn this into a clickable link, and i can't figure out what i am doing wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57826035/i-want-to-turn-this-into-a-clickable-link-and-i-cant-figure-out-what-i-am-doin)

Comment: What are all of the various URLs you are trying to actually access ultimately?

Comment: Some of your questions doesn't make sense, *"s there a way to turn Load an Id inside of an href element"* Please, explain what is this? What is a "Load"? `href` is not an element, is a property. If you need help, please, try to be more clear. Why can't you just add the url directly into `href`? why to use `id`?

Comment: when you load the a , load it to href attribute instead of text

Comment: @samanime they are various URls that are defined based on a json response the end result of where this url should send is here https://braytech.org/2/4611686018429000034/(JSON response)/legend"

Comment: Could you update your answer to include a sample of the mappings, like "this key" -> "/some-url", etc. so we can more precisely answer. It's not 100% clear where you want it to go just looking at it.

Comment: I updated it Extensively does that help? @samanime

Comment: Updated the answer text is coming from js but instead of .text you should do attr href

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var fstats = "SomethingLoaded";
  var webLink = "braytech.org/2/4611686018429000034/"+ fstats + "/legend";
  $('#player-f-stats').text(fstats);
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#player-web-Link").attr("href", webLink);
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
display: block;
margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="player-f-stats"></h1>
<a href="#" id="player-web-Link">View in Depth Stats</a>

<button class="button">Change href</button>
```

FIXING YOUR SYNTAX ERROR:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny/2/Account/4611686018429000034/",
    headers: {
      "X-API-Key": "47b810e692d64237911c2cbe0d433cfe"
    }
  }).done(function(json) {

  });
  $(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny/2/Account/4611686018429000034/",
        headers: {
          "X-API-Key": apiKey
        },
        success: function(data) {
       var fstats = data.Response.data.characters[0].characterBase.characterId;
       var webLink = "braytech.org/2/4611686018429000034/"+ fstats + "/legend";
       $('#player-f-stats').text(fstats);
       $("#player-web-Link").attr("href", webLink);
       }
});
});
```

Comment: Thank You This is exactly what i was trying to do

Comment: ok @evik Ghazarian its pulling up the link as a link, however rather than loading the new webpage its just refreshing the page essentially.

Comment: can you please explain more

Comment: so when i load the page https://beatsbycayde.com/test/ it  pulls up https://braytech.org/2/4611686018429000034/2305843009219164130/legend as i clickable link   and i can click on it , but when i click on it the page just refreshes and i am still at https://beatsbycayde.com/test/

Comment: looking at the link your href is not changing. you are doing something wrong. right click inspect the link. it is not changing

Comment: exactly, I can't figure out why

Comment: did you import jquery

Comment: I had ttried importing jquery yes OK i am trying to fix the missing ")"

Comment: fixed your syntax error if you cant find it look at the bottom part of the answer

Comment: let me know once you done I remove. Plus not a good practice that you expose your api key to public

Comment: oh ok thank you i'll change that . i updated it but now it is adding beatsbycayde.com to the beginning of the link

Comment: your whole structure is wrong document ready shall not be in ajax